# Firestore break out of a query

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs

I have code as below to not to write to DB if the same post has already been posted.

I put a `return` but `self.addtoDB()` is still executed.  What is the right way to check for an existing post and not write to DB if it exists?

```
db.collection("posts")
    .where("ytid", "==", self.youtubeId)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        alert("This gameplay has already been posted");
        return;
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
  self.addToDB();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all functions that return a promise, get() returns immediately, the callback you provide to `then` will be invoked some time later after the query completes.  Your code continues on to execute `self.addToDB()` immediately after that, without waiting for the results.  You should instead do **all** of your conditional processing inside that callback.

```
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
        const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        alert("This gameplay has already been posted");
      }
      else {
        self.addToDB();
      }
    })
```